# React passing data via props vs method call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say I have a component X which renders a text input field + a child component Y. Y uses the text from the input field to render something else.

To get the data, X listens for a change event from the text field, and then grabs its updated content via a ref.

Now as I understand it I can pass the data to child Y in two ways.

1) X stores the new data in its state, so its render method is triggered, and here I pass the data to Y using props like `<Y something={data}/>`

2) X calls a method on Y by using it ref like `this.refs.y.setSomething(data)`. In this case I don't need to store the data in the state of X.

So apart from storing state in X, what are the reasons to choose one over the other?

Comment: I added as a comment as it's not an answer to this question. A third way it's using Fluxxor. Creating a store accessible from all components, avoiding all props passing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the data into the child component using props, as in the [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html). You can think of the props as the function arguments for the child components.

Other than being the idiomatic way to do this in React, I can think of a few reasons why you should do this. Firstly, calling a method like `this.refs.y.setSomething(data)` will mean that you need to implement code for storing the state in Y. So you haven't had to set state in X, but you do it in Y instead.

More importantly, if X for some reason unmounts Y during a re-render and then later remounts it, you will have lost the state in Y. But if you are passing in props, then Y would receive the same props before and after it's unmounted.

Comment: Thanks, it's clear to me now. I was using the material-ui components and lot of them have methods to set and get data so I started to wonder. But I understand that the state (if any) should live in the parent component X and not the owned component Y.